# EF Core Cosmos 3.0.0 incompatible with .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

In an ASP.NET Core (v 2.1.1) web app I'd like to use EF Core with Cosmos DB. For this I need to add the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos` package.

I'm able to install the `old 2.2.0-preview3-35497` NuGet.

However the current `3.0.0-preview8.19405.11` NuGet complains that

```
NU1202
Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos 3.0.0-preview8.19405.11 
is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1).
Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos 3.0.0-preview8.19405.11
supports: netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1)
```

To me the error sounds like this EF Core provider suppors only .NET and not .NET Core in the latest version.

Which is completely unexpected for an EF Core provider.

Do I understand the error correctly, why such strange change in the new version and how to fix it?

Comment: What version of .NET Core are you using? I'm pretty sure you need to use .NET Core 3 preview8.

Comment: The EF Core 3.0 packages require .NET Core 3.0, which in turn requires all the ASP.NET Core packages be 3.0 packages as well. In short, if you need the latest EF Core, you need to upgrade your app to an ASP.NET Core 3.0 app.

Comment: Also, .NET Standard is not .NET Framework. It's basically an interface layer that allows interop between compatible versions of .NET Framework, .NET Core, Unity, Xamarin, etc. However, .NET Standard 2.1 (not to be confused with 2.0) is *only* implemented currently by .NET Core 3.0.

Answer (score 2):

This error is because .Net Core 3.0 look to .net standard 2.1 (not disponible officially). But, Visual Studio is already compatible.

**Open your .csproj** and edit *TargetFramework* tag to "netstandard2.1": `<TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>`

Make it to all projects and probably works ;p